# Red angle in image by using Picasso

Tags: android, image-processing, picasso

I use Picasso to load and show pictures in ViewPager.

Viewpager adapter:

```
private List<ImageItem> bannerList;
ViewPager pager = get();
Picasso p = new Picasso.Builder(RefApplication.getInstance())
        .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient))
        .build();

    p.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
    p.setLoggingEnabled(true);

    pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
        private ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp =
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                );

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return bannerList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return com.annimon.stream.Objects.equals(view, object);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(container.getContext());
            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(container.getContext());


            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(activity);
            final ImageItem item = bannerList.get(position);

            p.load(item.imageUrl()).into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });

            imageView.setOnClickListener(view -> item.onClick().onClick(imageView));

            layout.addView(imageView, lp);
            layout.addView(progressBar, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
            container.addView(layout, lp);
            return layout;
        }
    });
```

There are red angles on each photo. How to remove it? I try remove fit and center crop, ineffectually.

Versions: okhttp:2.5.0 picasso:2.5.2 supportLib 23.1.1 android 5.0+

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the debug indicator. More details here:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

If you don't want to see it just call:

```
p.setIndicatorsEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a indicator to show from where the image is loaded

If you don't want to see it just replace:

```
p.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
```

with

```
p.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide Indicator replace:

```
p.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
```

with

```
p.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
```